# Converter failed to convert value of type 'system.datetime' to type 'datetime' in windows phone 8.1 Datepicker

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, datepicker, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating a windows phone 8.1 app using MVVM pattern. I have used datepicker, and I want to get the value(date) of the **datepicker** in the viewModel, so I have binded this with a property in the viewModel. After running this app I am getting an error in the output window of Visual Studio.

**Error: Converter failed to convert value of type 'System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' to type 'DateTime'; BindingExpression: Path='Date' DataItem='App1.ViewModel.MainViewModel'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.DatePicker' (Name='null'); target property is 'Date' (type 'DateTime').**

Here is my,
Xaml view:

```
<DatePicker Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="26,-0.333,0,0.5"
                Date="{Binding Date}"
                />
```

ViewModel Property:

```
 private DateTime _date;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set
        {
            _date = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me in solving this error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Date` property of the `DatePicker` is a `DateTimeOffset` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datepicker.date.aspx))

That means you can't *directly* bind it to a `DateTime` object, as no conversion exists. However, `DateTimeOffset` has a convienent property, `DateTime` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/system.datetimeoffset.datetime.aspx)) that **is** a `DateTime`.

So just change your binding to:

```
Date="{Binding Date.DateTime}"
```

Or bind against a `DateTimeOffset` property and convert it yourself later.

Comment: Thanks @BradleyDotNet! I have changed the property to DateTimeOffset and the error has gone now. But the value of the property which I am getting now is 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM +00:00. Can you tell me how to get the current date?

Comment: @UtsavDawn That indicates a non-set value. Did the user not select a date yet?

Comment: I have just checked it, and got that the user has selected a value from the datepicker, but I am still getting the same value.

Comment: @UtsavDawn Did you set the mode to `TwoWay`? IIRC the default binding mode in WP is "OneWay"

Comment: thanks after making it `TwoWay` it worked! Another thing is that the default date on the datepicker is showing 1/1/1915. Can you tell me how to set it to current date?

Comment: @UtsavDawn The easiest way would be to initialize your backing property, ie: `Date = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now);`

Comment: I also stumbled upon this problem, but was somehow confused by this answer. When the `Date` property expects a `DateTimeOffset`, why do you suggest using "Date.DateTime" in the binding, as this would provide the wrong data type? Or did I miss something there? Other than that, using the Offset type really does work, so thanks :)

Comment: @Bexo Good point... You could use that technique if you were doing an `ElementName` binding but that wouldn't really help against a view model. Can't remember what I was thinking when I wrote that so I *could* have been on to something...